# Create new php var which increments from previous var without changing the inital var in PHP

Tags: php, variables, increment

I need to take a variable of the current month (in this case output as the number "1") - and output it is the numbers "02" and "03". I'm trying to do this:

```
<?php $current_month = "{current_time format="%m"}"; 
$next_month = "0".$current_month++; 
$third_month = "0".$next_month++; 
?>
```

but this is changing the original variable, which I don't want to do. How do I accomplish this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `+ 1`:

```
<?php 
$current_month = "{current_time format="%m"}"; 
$next_month = "0". ($current_month + 1); 
$third_month = "0". ($next_month + 2); ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't evaluations be placed in the parenthesis?